# Navigation bar is not working the way I want t to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the design of the navbar appearing when scrolling down and main navbar to appear when on the top.

Instead when scrolling down design is changing but when moving back to the top it is not changing to the main one and another navbar is appearing as soon as I start scrolling, but I want it to appear when the main one is hiding which is after `70px` high.

I am working on my own website and not good with codes yet. When I am scrolling down I want to appear another content of the navbar and when I am on the top, original navbar is appearing.

I want this to be done in pure JavaScript with no libraries or framewokrs. Please see codes below and I know that codes are not organised. I will do that later on.

**No Libraries or Framworks, Please**

```js
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
var appear = document.querySelector(".appear")

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 70) {
    hide.style.display = "block";
    appear.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    hide.style.display = "none";
    appear.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3FA9A5;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.hide {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Long Cang', cursive;
  display: block;
}

.appear {
  height: 70px;
  display: none;
}

.appear img {
  width: 210px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
}

.post {
  margin-left: 4.165%;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
}

#post-divide {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.comments {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 68.5px;
  padding-bottom: 293.5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Long+Cang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="hide">Unknown</li>
      <li class="appear"><img src="cat.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="profile text">
        <img id="main" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/86629641/superthumb.jpg?t=1384568664">
        <hr>
        <p>12 posts</p>
        <p>instagram</p>
        <button>Subscribe!</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="post">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div>
          <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
        </div>
        <hr id="post-divide">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="comments text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1 center">
      <div class="post">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div>
          <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
        </div>
        <hr id="post-divide">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="comments text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.scrollY` to get the position. I've modified your code below. 
Hope this helps. Best Wishes

```js
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
var appear = document.querySelector(".appear")

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY < 70) {
    hide.style.display = "block";
    appear.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    hide.style.display = "none";
    appear.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3FA9A5;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.hide {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Long Cang', cursive;
  display: block;
}

.appear {
  height: 70px;
  display: none;
}

.appear img {
  width: 210px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
}

.post {
  margin-left: 4.165%;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
}

#post-divide {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.comments {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 68.5px;
  padding-bottom: 293.5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Long+Cang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="hide">Unknown</li>
      <li class="appear"><img src="cat.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="profile text">
        <img id="main" src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/86629641/superthumb.jpg?t=1384568664">
        <hr>
        <p>12 posts</p>
        <p>instagram</p>
        <button>Subscribe!</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="post">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div>
          <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
        </div>
        <hr id="post-divide">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="comments text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1 center">
      <div class="post">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div>
          <img id="image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/d4/8c/76d48cb2928845dfcfab697ac7cbcf1c.jpg">
        </div>
        <hr id="post-divide">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="comments text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having 2 classes which in this example are named:

```
.bluebackground{
    background-color:blue;
}

.redbackground{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Just so we can notice the changes. Next up we add the navigationBar id to the nav tag:

```
<nav id="navigationBar">
```

Followed by the next script:

```
var navbar = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
window.onscroll = function(){
    if(document.body.scrollTop > 70){
        navbar.classList.remove("bluebackground");
        navbar.classList.add("redbackground");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.add("bluebackground");
        navbar.classList.remove("redbackground");
    }
}
```

Now you can adjust the design working in 2 or even more classes.